# Managing django secrets

Tags: python, django, docker

I am creating a Django web application that will be hosted in AWS.  I'm developing on my laptop (Mac) and using docker compose to run a postgres database in AWS as well.  Accordingly, sometimes I am using a development database from my Mac in PyCharm, and other times I need to compile and run the docker to test that the functionality works in the container.

The challenge I am facing is the management of secrets across all of these locations.  It would be ideal to have one "secret vault" which could be accessed at run-time from either within the docker or within PyCharm to keep life simpler.  I am familiar with .env files and the manner by which these can be imported, but this also requires me to copy them into the docker container at build time.

Is there some "simple yet robust" way to manage this more easily?  It feels like having copies of different .env files in different environments presents its own risks.

Comment: Have all secrets in all places and then check on runtime which secret you want to use based on a flag like IS_PRODUCTION

Comment: Thinking about this further, it seems a good way would be to create a separate "docker secret server" that could be called by both a dev and prod server at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I chose to utilize Amazon Secrets Manager (https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) for this purpose.  In this way, I only need to worry about two key values in order to safeguard all of my variables.  I have edited my .profile file (both in my local and in my docker environment) to include:

```
export aws_access_key_id=AWSPUBLICKEY
export aws_secret_access_key=AWSSUPERSECRETKEY
```

Within Python, I then import the environment variables and can then access the secrets from AWS as follows (note that I had to reference "secret_name" using the full arn address):

```
import boto3
import base64
import os
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# Use this code snippet in your app.
# If you need more information about configurations or implementing the sample code, visit the AWS docs:
# https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/python/

# add aws_access_key_id / aws_secret_access_key to environment variables
global AWS_ACCESS
global AWS_SECRET

AWS_ACCESS = os.environ.get('aws_access_key_id')
AWS_SECRET = os.environ.get('aws_secret_access_key')

def get_secret():
    secret_name = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:547847502175:secret:python_multiple_test-rQR9qo"
    region_name = "us-east-1"

    #print(AWS_ACCESS)
    #print(AWS_SECRET)
    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET,
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    # In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    # See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    # We rethrow the exception by default.

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            # Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            # An error occurred on the server side.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            # You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            # You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            # We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])

    # Your code goes here.
    print(secret)
```

In this way, my Python code can be kept as clean as possible, relying upon the key retrieval to access my secret passwords.